# Browser (Extension Script) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: webpack

I am requiring a module (chinese-tokenizer) that uses fs. Webpack prompts an error that fs is not found. All solutions that I found online suggest to use target: 'node', however my application is meant for the 'web'.

Is there a way to avoid this error while still have the module work?

Answer (score 1):

The issue probably happened because you are using Webpack 5. Traditionally, Webpack used to polyfill the core Node.js modules when the bundle was being created for browser/web. But that is no longer the case.

To address this, essentially, you will have to tell Webpack to polyfill this module. There are multiple options to do this.

First, you can use `node-polyfill-webpack-plugin` that takes cares of bundling any core Node.js module that Webpack encounters.

In you Webpack configuration, `webpack.config.js` file, just add [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin):

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  // Other config...
  plugins: [
    new NodePolyfillPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Second, you can write your own configuration to tell Webpack about this module:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // Other configuration
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      fs: require.resolve('fs')
    }
  }
};
```

Third, instead of using actual module, you can provide your own mocked implementation. This is what you should use as bundling actual `fs` modules doesn't make any sense for browser code and probably there will be transitive dependencies of `fs` modules that Webpack may fail to bundle. See [this link](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvefallback) for more details.

Also, make sure that you are not using the `loadFile` function provided by the  `chinese-tokenizer` module. That is the only function using the Node's `fs` module.